# If a function $F$ is continuous and bounded in $[0,\infty)$, then $F$ is integrable?

Tags: integration

I was wondering if it is true to say that: if a function is continuous and bounded in $[0,\infty)$, then $F$ is integrable?

Answer (score 2):

No, consider $F: [0, \infty ) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}, F(x)=1$ which is continuous and bounded in $[0, \infty)$. But $\lim_{y\rightarrow \infty}\int_0^y F(x) dx = \infty$. Hence $F$ is not integrable.